# Spring Cloud Stream rabbit binder causing circular dependency error when using connection-prefix property

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

Application failed to start when I use connection-name-prefix property, if I remove prefix property app starts without issues

`spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.binder.connection-name-prefix=myPrefix`

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   binderHealthIndicator defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.config.RabbitServiceAutoConfiguration$RabbitHealthIndicatorConfiguration
      ↓
   rabbitTemplate defined in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitTemplateConfiguration
┌─────┐
|  rabbitConnectionFactory defined in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator
↑     ↓
|  org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.config.RabbitMessageChannelBinderConfiguration (field private org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.config.RabbitMessageChannelBinderConfiguration.rabbitConnectionFactory)
└─────┘
```

I have single binder app with 5 processors and looking to customize connection factory name

- spring-boot-starter-parent: 2.3.3.RELEASE
- spring-cloud: Hoxton.SR6

```
spring.cloud.stream.binders.simple-rabbit.environment.spring.rabbitmq.host=host
spring.cloud.stream.binders.simple-rabbit.environment.spring.rabbitmq.username=user
spring.cloud.stream.binders.simple-rabbit.environment.spring.rabbitmq.password=pswd

spring.cloud.stream.binders.simple-rabbit.type=rabbit
spring.cloud.stream.binders.simple-rabbit.environment.spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.cloud.stream.binders.simple-rabbit.default-candidate=false
spring.cloud.stream.binders.simple-rabbit.inherit-environment=false
spring.cloud.stream.binders.simple-rabbit.environment.spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.enabled=true
spring.cloud.stream.binders.simple-rabbit.environment.spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.initial-interval=1000ms
spring.cloud.stream.binders.simple-rabbit.environment.spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.max-attempts=3 
spring.cloud.stream.binders.simple-rabbit.environment.spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.max-interval=10000ms
spring.cloud.stream.binders.simple-rabbit.environment.spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.multiplier=1
spring.cloud.stream.binders.simple-rabbit.environment.spring.rabbitmq.publisher-confirms=true
spring.cloud.stream.binders.simple-rabbit.environment.spring.rabbitmq.publisher-returns=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.binder.connection-name-prefix=myFactory
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.binder=simple-rabbit
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=dest
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=group
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.max-attempts=1
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.queueNameGroupOnly=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.exchange-type=fanout
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.prefetch=100
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.acknowledge-mode=MANUAL
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.max-concurrency=2
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.consumer-tag-prefix=consumerprefix
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.quorum.enabled=true
```

```
@EnableBinding(SimpleBinder.class)
public class SimpleProcessor {

    @StreamListener(target = SimpleBinder.INPUT, copyHeaders = "false")
    public void processMessage(@Payload byte[] payload, @Headers Map<String, Object> headers,
            @Header(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL) Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long deliveryTag)
            throws Exception {

    }

    public interface SimpleBinder {

        /**
         * Input channel name
         */
        final String INPUT = "input";

        /**
         * @return input channel
         */
        @Input(INPUT)
        SubscribableChannel handleMessage();

    }
}
```

here is the app pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>circular-dependency</groupId>
    <artifactId>cd-jar</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <name>mq-publisher</name>
    <description>publisher</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8
        </project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <jenkins.buildnumber>x</jenkins.buildnumber>
        <mongo-in-memory-mongo>1.28.0</mongo-in-memory-mongo>
        <jenkins.branchName>LOCALHOST</jenkins.branchName>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR6</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>mq-publisher-${project.version}.${jenkins.buildnumber}
        </finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <additionalProperties>
                                <buildnumber>${project.version}.${jenkins.buildnumber}
                                </buildnumber>
                                <branchName>${jenkins.branchName}</branchName>
                            </additionalProperties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>target/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>com/Test.class
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: It works fine for me with Hoxton.SR8 (and SR6); edit the question to show your complete configuration.

Comment: @GaryRussell updated question with complete config

Comment: Need your yaml/properties and Pom too.

Comment: @GaryRussell added following to question
1) Error
2) application.properties
3) Binder class
4) pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce it with your config (but the name wasn't applied to the connection). I **was** able to reproduce it with

```
spring.cloud.stream.binders.simple-rabbit.type=rabbit
spring.cloud.stream.binders.simple-rabbit.environment.spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.binder.connection-name-prefix=myPrefix

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-in-0.binder=simple-rabbit
```

Why do you need `simple-rabbit` as a named binder? It works ok when the binder is at the top level.

If you must have it as a named binder, I'll see if I can come up with a work around.

**EDIT**

This seems to work ok...

```java
@EventListener
public void eventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    event.getApplicationContext().getBean(CachingConnectionFactory.class).setConnectionNameStrategy(
            conn -> "myConnection#" + this.incr.incrementAndGet());
}
```

(Instead of setting it via a property).